# “What is given, can be taken away” says Yonn Rogg

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

Given that Carol Danvers is infused with the energy from the Tesseract or Space Stone in *Captain Marvel*, why does Yonn Rogg claim that her powers can be taken away?

Or was this just an attempt by the Kree to keep ‘Vers under their control through manipulation without actually being able to remove her powers? Or does he believe that the Kree blood given to her is her source of power?

Comment: I definitely think it's a manipulation tactic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## He is lying (kinda).

Vers has had **a device implanted on her neck to restrain her powers**. The Kree told her it helped her focus them, but it was a lie. The powers weren't given, and can't be taken away, but they can be subdued.

In fact, when she is being subjugated by the AI for the last time, she burns the device off and claims

> I've been fighting with one arm tied behind my back. But what happens when... I'm finally set free.